# URL launcher conflicting with google map location picker flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need to use both URL launcher  and google map location picker, but both are conflicting with each other burning me this error :

```
Because url_launcher >=6.0.6 depends on url_launcher_platform_interface ^2.0.3 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, url_launcher >=6.0.6 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0.
And because geolocator_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.2, url_launcher >=6.0.6 is incompatible with geolocator_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety.0.
And because google_map_location_picker >=4.1.3 depends on geolocator ^6.1.14 which depends on geolocator_platform_interface ^1.0.8, url_launcher >=6.0.6 is incompatible with google_map_location_picker >=4.1.3.
So, because vendor depends on both google_map_location_picker ^4.1.7 and url_launcher ^6.0.9, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Here are the versions I use :

```yaml
  google_map_location_picker: ^4.1.7
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9
```

Comment: how about removing removing version numbers from those , like ` google_map_location_picker:` and `url_launcher:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the error `url_launcher` bigger or equals version: 6.0.6 has the newest `plugin_platform_interface version` (2.0.0). And because `google_map_location_picker` has the old one you should use **`url_launcher: ^6.0.5`** it will solve your problem.

Comment: great that worked, but how did you found out the specific version that works for this? because I have many other conflicts